# Cannot set Paths and sourcing in .bash_profile

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, bash

new to linux's inner workings.
I have accrued a lot of executable scripts since I started, I was told I wasted a lot of time typing their full paths every time I wanted to use them so it was suggested to add the paths into my `.bash_profile` so I did as follows

```
PATH=$HOME/bin/Tools/cif2cell-1.1.5:$HOME/bin/Tools/cteprouts:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin/Tools
export $PATH

. $HOME/bin/AtomsScriptsNG/bin/src/settings.sh
source $HOME/bin/AtomsScriptsNG/bin/src/settings.sh
```

I am connecting to a cluster computer which runs on the Unix language using `putty.exe` (not sure if it makes a difference).

When I login with the above `.bash_profile` I get the following errors

```
-bash: export: `/home/eg205/bin/Tools/cif2cell-1.1.5:/home/eg205/bin/Tools/ctepro uts:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/home/eg205/bin:/home/eg205/bin:/home/eg205/bin/Tools': not a valid identifier
-bash: /home/eg205/bin/AtomsScriptsNG/bin/src/settings.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /export71/home/eg205/bin/AtomsScriptsNG/bin/src/settings.sh: No such file or directory
```

I'm sure I'm making some glaring mistake... how do I set it up correctly to load the `AtomsScruptsNG` environment from the `settings.sh` and look in the directories `bin`, `cif2cell-1.1.5` and `cteprouts` for the scripts I run often?

Comment: `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin/Tools:$HOME/bin/Tools/cif2cell-1.1.5:$HOME/bin/Tools/cteprouts`. Also Why do you define the path twice. And it looks as though those scripts dont exist/ are called something different/ are somewhere else.

Comment: To be frank a colleague wrote this and I have no idea how it works of yet. So I was reading up on paths. Actually those that you mentioned are directories that hold the scripts, `$HOME/bin/Tools/cif2cell-1.1.5/cif2cell` is the path to the script itself. What I understand he was trying to do is direct the search for executables to a list of directories (`cif2cell-1.1.5` and `cteprouts`)

Comment: May be that because you path isn't defined it cant find them then ? If they do exist and are there then using the export statement in my above comment instead of the top 3 lines should solve the problem

Comment: Thank you, your solution works for the paths, any ideas on the source?

Comment: Ah never mind I did make a mistake in defining the source path. Thank you for your help! Have a nice day!

Comment: I dont think you want to be using source. Instead just execute the script. E.g just write `$HOME/bin/AtomsScriptsNG/bin/src/settings.sh.`

Comment: Ok, may I ask for what reason? Not to doubt your advice, it seems to be working but I don't know better, a little explenation would be very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: In fact it depends what those scripts do ? If they set environment variables for the shell then its valid. If not then you dont really need to source the script and can just run it normally.

Comment: They do in fact set variables and load modules for a specific environment which are modules I need now and then. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing the $ from your export line like this:

```
export PATH
```

this will tell the shell to export the variable 'PATH' and not it's "contents/value".

One thing to have in mind concerning shells: every line you pass into a shell, either by typing or by feeding it scripts, will be executed AFTER all substitutions have been made. so everything which looks like $FOOBAR  will be replaced by the contents of the variable FOOBAR.

if every variable has been succesfully replaced the whole commandline will be executed by the shell.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer! That was the issue for the paths, however the source still doesn't accept the `.sh` file, any ideas?

Comment: Ah never mind I did make a mistake in defining the source path. Thank you for your help! Have a nice day!